# Animate image location different after returning to page

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a tabbed application for iPad. On the first tab I have a separate menu with a pointer that highlights the currently active menu button. The pointer (a UIImage) is animated into position after tapping the button.

The problem is when you leave the highlighted image on any button that's not the original/default button and move to another tab in the application, then back again, the image has moved back to the default location. However, when you tap another button the image moves in the wrong direction. I think it's because the image moves back but the old coordinates are retained, or the other way around? It's a bit hit and miss and behaves differently testing in the simulator compared to directly on the iPad.

I think I need to start with absolute coordinates and stick with them throughout the process. But I can't get my head around how to achieve it with the CGAffine functions.

Here is my current code

```
- (IBAction)diplayForm1:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    buttonHighlightImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (IBAction)diplayForm2:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    buttonHighlightImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 80);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (IBAction)diplayForm3:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    buttonHighlightImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 160);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

EDIT - - -

@Mundi I tried the code you suggested. I'm assuming by newFrame you mean define a new UIImageView and property which I did in the .h (I called it 'sfh'), then @synthesize in the .m.

This is my code in the .m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // The "pointer" and the "old" frame are the same so I thought it pointless to do
    // selectedFormHighlight.frame = selectedFormHighlight.frame;

    // I tried anyway and also tried this and many other combinations
    selectedFormHighlight.frame = sfh.frame;

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        selectedFormHighlight.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
    }];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

When I run this the pointer animates off the screen (top-left) and doesn't come back. I have tried every possible combination I can think of in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear but it makes no difference. I tried removing the other lines in viewDidAppear and it still does the same thing.

I think you're suggesting to animate the pointer from the original (default) position when the user returns from another screen. I don't want that, it should simply remain in the same spot where they left it without animation. Or at least put it back there without them realizing it. The only animation is when they choose to tap a different button within that view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the help from @Mundi but couldn't get it to work that way. I eventually arrived at the following code.

```
// This initially sets the frame with a variable value that 
// corresponds to the current child view
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    selectedFormHighlight.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.getY, 250, 4100);
}

// Button actions (converted to a single action instead of one for each button)
// This was done by referencing a tag added to each button (the button tags 
// match the children's tags)
-(IBAction)goToForm:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    self.currentChild = self.formViewControllers[btn.tag];
    [UIView beginAnimations.nil context:NULL];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        selectedFormHighlight.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.getY, 250, 4100);
    }];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    sfh.frame = selectedFormHighlight.frame;
}

// This returns the 'y' (vertical center position) of the pointer 
// frame for each of the child views
-(int)getY {
    switch(_currentChild.view.tag) {
        case 1:
            return -2005;
            break;
        case 2:
            return -1925;
            break;
        default:
            return -1845;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing this is that the actual view object and its presentation layer get mixed up when the view is hidden and redisplayed. The solution is to change the view properties rather than animate the layers.

Thus, you do not need to use affine transforms. Just set the new position of the pointer view directly by changing its `frame` or `center`.

The more up-to-date format to do this is with block based animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
   pointer.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

Also, it seems very inefficient to have three methods just differing by one variable. You could just multiply the desired y position by 80.

**Edit**:

Another reason your button resets is because that is where it was put when the view is instantiated. Just set the position of your view in `viewWillAppear` of your view controller and then animate it to the new location in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Hi @Mundi, sorry I'm new to this can you give me some more info. How do you make a frame? I tried your code but with the center method using `buttonHighlightImage.center = CGPointMake(125, 205);` but it still resets the image location after returning to the page. Otherwise how do you create the newFrame?

Comment: I tried using the center of the button as a reference `buttonHighlightImage.center = CGPointMake(buttonHighlightImage.center.x, button1.center.y);` but it still resets after returning to the page.

Comment: Can you please show some more code? I have tried so many things and don't exactly know what code to implement to achieve what you're suggesting. It seems to make no difference to the position for anything added to viewWillAppear when returning to the page.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use absolute coordinates?

Comment: There is not much code necessary. In `viewWillAppear` you write `pointer.frame = old.frame;` and in `viewDidAppear` the above. And yes, of course you are using "absolute" coordinates.

Comment: This should work now. You just have to get your frames right (i.e. the correct "old" frame in `willAppear` and the correct "to" frame in `didAppear`):